# Cardinal-direction latitude and longitude to decimal

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geospatial

I'm attempt to extract latitudes and longitudes from [some of NOAA's weather bulletins](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/marine/wxitsu.htm). The issue is that the lat and longs use cardinal direction to indicate in which direction the lat or long offset is — not "pure" decimal, which indicates the direction of the offset by the number's sign (i.e. positive or negative).

Retrieving the coordinates:

```
    >>> import urllib2, re
    >>> url = 'http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/raw/we/weca43.pheb.tib.cax.txt'
    >>> request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    >>> re.search('COORDINATES\s+-\s+(.*)', request.read()).groups()[0]
    '60.6 SOUTH   25.4 WEST'
```

I can parse them, but as there are a number of ways to go about accomplishing that, I wanted to know what I should keep in mind while attempting a solution.

Also, Google understands such coordinates, but there doesn't seem to an API to parse it.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what help you need.  South latitudes are conventionally negative, as are west longitudes. I guess you know this much already and you tell us that you can already parse the text extracted from the bulletins -- what else do you think you might need to bear in mind ?

Comment: Thanks for accept, you also my upvote; click on arrow up

Comment: I actually didn't meant to accept, but meant to upvote :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you find the word "SOUTH" multiply that latitude "60.6" with -1.
if you find the word "WEST" multiply that longitude 25.4 with -1.

This is all!

you get (-60.6, -25.4) which is the decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution used:

```
import urllib2, re
url = 'http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/raw/we/weca43.pheb.tib.cax.txt'
request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
coordinates = re.search('COORDINATES\s+-\s+(.*)', request.read()).groups()[0]

p = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')
matches = p.split(coordinates)
matches = [match.split(' ') for match in matches]
for coordinate in matches:
    m = -1 if coordinate[1].upper() in ('SOUTH', 'WEST') else 1
    coordinate[0] = float(coordinate[0]) * m
coordinates = (matches[1][0], matches[0][0])
```